# How to get Logged in user detail before redirecting to page after authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I am developing an web backend for swiggy type of application. In that back-end i want to display all restaurants added by that particular partner user in header and that drop-down will display on all pages, so i want to do that get all restaurants and store on some place so that header can access and display it on every page. so how to do this? I am try to execute below code

```
if (Auth::guard('partner')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
        $user = $userId = Auth::id();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($user);
        exit;
        return redirect('partners/employees');
    }
```

but it gives me error not able to get user id. i want to display user's restaurants list which is added by current user in system on every page header as dropdown list. so how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can access user id like this

```
$userId = Auth::guard('partner')->user()->id;
```

Comment: no i am not able to access it. If i am using this then i got error like "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: You should try Auth::guard('partner')->user(); this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::user()->id;
```

Also... this is weird. Typo?

```
$user = $userId = Auth::id();

$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$user = Auth::user();
```